# Swapping last two nibbles in a block

Tags: python, binary

I am trying to swap the last two nibbles in the decNum block. any idea how i can implement that in this code:

```
list = [132, 201, 141, 74, 140, 94, 141, 140, 141, 15, 31, 164, 90, 229, 201, 141, 78, 114, 241, 217, 141, 217, 140, 180, 141, 164, 51, 141, 188, 221, 31, 164, 241, 177, 141, 140, 51, 217, 141, 201, 229, 152, 141, 78, 241, 114, 78, 102, 94, 141, 74, 152, 31, 152, 141, 94, 201, 31, 164, 102, 164, 51, 90, 141, 201, 229, 164, 31, 201, 152, 152, 51, 115]
key = 84
decrypted = []
for number in list:
    decNum = number | key
    bytes = bin(decNum)
    print(decNum," Bin:",bytes)
```

For example if it was given number 6 (00000110) it should swap the last two nibbles around , so output should be 9(00001001)

Comment: You mean swap the nibbles in each number? Don't use reserved word `list` as a variable

Comment: what output are you looking for?

Comment: @helloV If it were [reserved](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#keywords) he wouldn't have been able to use it. ;)

Comment: What is decNum **block**? What is nibbles in a block? Please clarify.

Comment: the number decNum, block im reffering to the 8bit binary value of that number, and a nibble is a 2bit chunk of that binary number, so basically what im trying to do is swap the last 2 binary digits with the second last 2 binary digits. Also sorry for not explaining what its for, its for a decryption algorithm where i have to use binary operations then convert the number that comes out to a letter using ascii code, so after its all done all those numbers in the list will make a sentence (though that wont happen till iv done the entire code not just this section)

Comment: Also , if i have a binary number 00010111, the outcome of this operation should return 0001110

Comment: A [nibble](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nibble) is four bits wide. You want to swap the last two pairs of bits?

Comment: Yes that is what I want to do, sorry iv been misinformed I was taught a nibble is a two pair of bits

Answer (score 2):

```
def swap_nibbles(byte:int) -> int:
    if byte >= 256: raise ValueError("Byte values must be 0..255")

    low_nibble = byte & 0x0F
    high_nibble = byte & 0xF0
    result = (high_nibble >> 4) | (low_nibble << 4)
    return result
```

You'll have to figure out where to call it, it isn't clear from your question what you're trying to do.

Comment: Thanks, just to confirm if this was given say int 6 (00000110) it should return (00001001)